# gdb catch throw and then ignore exceptions

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a crash in a multi threaded application and for whatever reason I can't manage to catch the exception before the stack is partially unwound.

So now I am trying to catch it by connected with gdb and using `catch throw`. However, I am getting lots of other unrelated and caught exceptions. How can I ignore those?

I tried `ignore 1 1000000`, but this doesn't ignore just the exception currently focused, but ignores all `catch throw` exceptions.

Any ideas how I can ignore that particular one only? e.g. maybe by file and line number?

Comment: If you're using C++11, you have to learn how to use `std::packaged_task` and then get the `std::future` from that task, which will forward all your exceptions to the main thread. Your thread *must* be exception-safe, otherwise it's just a bad design. `std::future` solves this problem elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 7.9, gdb has included some convenience functions like `$_caller_is` and `$_any_caller_is`.  These can be used as conditions on a breakpoint to make it stop only when a certain call stack is seen.

So, for example, if you know the spot at which the exception is thrown, you could do something like:

```
(gdb) catch throw if $_any_caller_is("functionname")
```

However, if you know the throwing function, it seems to me that it would be simpler to just set a breakpoint at that particular `throw`.

Another option in some situations is to filter the exception by type.  This functionality is built into `catch throw` since version 7.7.  This form accepts a regular expression matching the type name:

```
(gdb) catch throw NameOfType
```